# Computing Kronecker's polynomial $\Phi_N(X,Y)$ modulo $2$ for $N=23,33$

Tags: modular-forms

Kronecker's polynomial $\Phi_N(X,Y)\in\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ is used to give a model for the modular curve $X_0(N)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that it is hard to compute this polynomial in general, but is it feasible to compute it modulo $2$? Specifically, I'm interested in $\Phi_{23}(X,Y) \pmod{2}$ and in $\Phi_{33}(X,Y) \pmod{2}$.